# Bind one key to three modifier keys autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, keystroke

i wannna be able to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Middle Button</kbd> for simulating <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Button</kbd> with AutoHotkey. I did it for simulating two keys. And it worked but it is not working for three keys.

so i wrote that:

```
LAlt & MButton::Send {Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}{RButton Down}
keywait, LAlt
keywait, MButton
LAlt & MButton Up::Send {Ctrl Up}{Shift Up}{RButton Up}
return
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that the two keywait lines are never executed as you have your send action on the some line as the hotkey, this will make a one-line hotkey or remap

If you wish to execute multiple lines of code in one hotkey routine you will need to start the routine on the line below the hotkey definition label.

Also try taking a simpler approach be using Autohotkeys remapping capabilities

Can't say this will work for you but give it a shot

```
!MButton::^+RButton
```

Hope it helps